# Is there a modular inverse function in erlang? - Erlang

Tags: erlang, rsa

Im trying to recreate an RSA encryption program I had already made in Java into Erlang. I cannot figure out how to generate the private key though. My original java code:

```java
privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(phi);
```

I couldn't find any general algorithms to find the 'd' or private key online. most feature small simple equations that cannot be implemented in larger problems or the tutorial simply gives the private key without explaining the process. Can someone point me in a direction so I could learn to generate the private key? Or if there is a modular inverse function in Erlang, indicate what it is please.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: the actual equation to solve is [e*d mod (phi) = 1], where e is the public key, and d is the private key, and phi = [p-1][q-1]. I pretty much want to solve for d when all the other variables are known

EDIT2: Wolframalpha.com returns multiple possible values for d. How does that work?

Comment: Also, this seems really backward. Why are you trying to generate a privateKey from a publicKey? If you can do that computationally feasibly, that means it's feasible for anyone to break your encryption.

Comment: Look up "Modular multiplicative inverse" in Wikipedia.  It looks like there's a simple algorithm there.  However, if my understanding is correct, that won't help you find a private key, which requires the ability to break down a large composite number into two large prime factors.

Comment: P.S. I've changed the title, since this has nothing to do with the "modulo" operator and it's already confused someone.

Comment: Removing `[java]` as the answer won't be about Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I figured it might attract someone who would know how to do the math behind the modInverse() method.

Comment: You can read the code for BigInteger but for a better description of what it does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: @Cruncher, in fact this is the regular way to define a public and a private key,  for tis you need to know the Phy number (M in my algorithm) Phy = (P-1)*(Q-1) where P and Q are 2 big prime numbers. The public key itself contains N = P*Q. The difficulty to crack this key is that N is huge and there is no fast method to decompose it into P and Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code do the job, what is missing in the wolfram page is that you have to choose the solution greater than 2 and smaller than phi, and then there is one single solution.

**[edit]** add a test to detect when M and C are not relative primes and then return an error tuple more explicit than the arithmetic error reported previously

```
-module (decod).

-export ([private/2]).

% In the key generation you start by choosing P and Q 2 big primes
% N = P*Q
% M = (P-1)*(Q-1)
% C a number smaller than M such as gcd(M,C) = 1
% the public key is made of {N,C}
% then lets find U and V such as C*U + M*V = 1 and 2 < U < M
% the private key is {U,N}
private(M,C) when is_integer(M), is_integer(C), M > C-> 
    P = private1({M,0},{C,1}),
    adjust(P,M).


private1(_,{1,P}) -> P;
private1(_,{0,_}) -> {error,gcd_not_1};
private1({R1,U1},{R2,U2}=A2) ->
    F = R1 div R2,
    private1(A2,{R1-R2*F,U1-U2*F}).

adjust(R,_) when is_tuple(R) -> 
    R;
adjust(P1,M) when P1 =< 2 ->
    K = (2 - P1) div M + 1,
    P1 + K * M;
adjust(P1,M) when P1 >= M ->
    K = (P1 - M) div M + 1,
    P1 - K * M;
adjust(P1,_) -> P1.
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up taking a java example and slowly converting it to Erlang because I'm more experienced in java than erlang. Thank I will try out your code to see if it works better though, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

While ther might be something like this hidden somewhere in crypto or public_key modules it is not part of their public API.

Since Erlang has builtin big-integers (the normal integers can get practically arbitrary size) it is quite easy to implement [one of the usual algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) to calculate your value.

For example the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) would be particularly easy to implement with recursive functions.

Comment: I doubt Erlang/OTP implements the Extended Euclidian Algorithm. It relies on OpenSSL for most low-level crypto functions and it doesn't provide an API to generate RSA keys.

Comment: I ended up using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm too, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an inverse modulo, because technicly there's an infinit amount of solutions to an inverse modulo.

The only way you can recreate a usable version is by using the modulo itself

```
int rest = number%dividor;
int quotient = (number-rest)/dividor;

int modInv = dividor*quotient+rest;
```

Comment: The question was about modular arithmetic, not the modulo operator.  OK, I can see how the questioner confused things in the title.